# Space Partioning Tree optimization for knn using scikit-learn

Tags: python, scikit-learn, tfidfvectorizer

I have the following tf-idf based word vectors :

```
1. ip_vector : The input text
2. training_vectors for a bunch of texts in my corpus.
```

These vectors are built using `scikit-learn TfIdfVectorizer` and have the default `L2 normalization` .

Now I am using scikit-learn's NearestNeighbor API with metric as `euclidean` and the `algorithm` as `ball_tree` and `kd_tree`.

`m = NearestNeighbors(metric='euclidean', algorithm='ball_tree')`
`m.fit(training_vectors)`
`op = m.kneighbors(ip_vector,5,return_distance=False)`
where both the `training_vectors` and `ip_vector` are TfIdfVectorized.

However this gives me poor results in terms of `time complexity` compared to letting the algorithm as `default` and  metric as `cosine` . I was expecting SPT based algorithms to be faster . What could be wrong here ?